# What is the best open source example of a lightweight Windows Application?

Tags: c++, c, windows, open-source

I would like to learn how a program can be written and installed without the use of the .net framework.  I'm looking for a project that is known to be lightweight and robust.  Something like the uTorrent client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/), the open-source project behind [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome), is chalk full of clean, robust (and unit-tested) code.  If you choose to dive in, keep the [map](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/getting-around-the-chrome-source-code) handy.

Comment: I think this is a great suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Try [Anki](http://ichi2.net/anki/), a spaced learning tool.

Comment: Interesting, I might start using this program!

Comment: This looks like an awesome program.

Comment: Is taking a dependency on QT really any better than on .NET if you are already planning on targetting only Windows?

Comment: @Eclipse: don't know how it was in '09, but they now support multiple platforms.  Guess it paid off?

Answer (score 3):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) seems like a nice, lightweight C++ Win32 program you can check out. Many features including a plugin system.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Win32 unmanaged code, C or C++

Nothing else !

Comment: What's wrong with this - it's absolutely the best way to get a very light-weight windows app running.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X).  It's an introduction to the basic Win32 API, which will let you do pretty much anything you want in windows without any extra outside dependencies.  It's not an open source app per se, but it does contain a number of full sample apps.

Answer (score 0):

I created a very small example C++ [windows application example](http://networkdls.com/Software.Asp?Review=24) years ago for this purpose. I'ts not robust at all but its cleanly written with no fluff. So if your looking for a really fresh start... check it out.