# What are some small, fast and lightweight open source applications (µTorrent -esque)?

Tags: c++, python, performance

> **Possible duplicate**
>   [What is the best open source example of a lightweight
>   Windows Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419096/what-is-the-best-open-source-example-of-a-lightweight-windows-application)

[µTorrent](http://utorrent.com) is a small bit-torrent client, a really small one.  It doesn't come with an installer, just a exe, you drop in your PATH somewhere.  It's super lightweight and yet feature rich.  Plus it is the work of one man.  It's also closed-source.

Many people have been curious about how it has been written, and there are hints here and there about a custom library etc.  But the question is, **are there any programs with attributes like µTorrent that are available with source code**--attributes like speed, small size, awesomeness.

Possible related question (/questions/9603/what-is-some-great-source-code-to-read), but think smaller than something like the Linux kernel.

**Clarification**:  I don't want examples of bit-torrent source code, but anything which is used by tons of people (validation of awesomeness) and also *fast, small and awesome!*

Comment: Any app used by Barney Stimpson ( from How I met your Mother ) should be `awesome`.

Comment: @Kirill: Thank you.

@Geo:  Yeah, I went overboard on the *awesomeness* of it all. :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should take a look at [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/) if you want to see a feature-rich *low-consumption of power* software :)

Comment: Of course it's low-power. That's what you can do if you confine yourself to writing OS-specific, non-portable software.

Comment: @Chris You make it sound a given. I've got a few dozen OS-specific, non-portable bloated pieces of crap who'd like to have a word with you ;)

Comment: @AraK: Thank you.  I've got the source, will be checking it out.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Chris:  Notepad++ is non portable, but then so is µTorrent ... I'm looking for something kick-ass ... if it is crossplatform then more points to it, but if it is not ... then so be it. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net)
It's the program that started all of the curiousity behind networks and how things WORK.
Everyone's looked at this source code.

Answer (score 1):

[rTorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) is a lightweight, feature-rich, console-only open-source torrent client.

Comment: @Ben S, while I agree, rTorrent is awesome I don't think the "bit-torrent" portion of the app is what he was interested in.  He wanted lean and mean applications with similar *qualities* to uTorrent.

Comment: @Ben S: thanks, but Simucal is right ... I wasn't interested in torrent programs per se.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Frhed](http://www.kibria.de/frhed.html), a simple open-source Windows hex editor.

Comment: Thanks, lemme have a look at it.  Is it yours?

Comment: I have no connection with it at all, other than using it.

Answer (score 0):

**[FRESHMEAT](http://freshmeat.net/)** is a great place to start. 
There are lots of small open source programs available that you can study.

Examples:

- [XML-RPC](http://freshmeat.net/projects/py-xmlrpc) specification.C implementation for Python. Its easy to learn and its fun.
- Heapq [`\Lib\heapq.py`] , xml-rpc [`\Lib\xmlrpc`] and lots of other codes in Python library are very well written.